# OpenGLのカメラについて

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl

初投稿でOpenGL初心者です。
androidでopenglを使って画像を描画する処理を
作っています。
一画面に複数の画像を描画して各画像をそれぞれ
ピンチインピンチアウトをする処理を実装
しようとしており、どのように実装しようか悩んでいます。
カメラとScaleGestureDetectorを
使って実現してみようと思っているのですが、各テクスチャにカメラを配置しないとできないように思っております。
そもそもカメラを複数配置することなどできるのでしょうか？

OpenGLは2.0を使用しています。
画像はbitmap化してtextureに送って頂点データとUVデータを計算し描画させています。

以下イメージです。
汚くてすみません。。

[image: イメージ]